# How to get url query parameters without Vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I don't need routing for my Vue app so I didn't add the Vue router package to my project.

Given the following sample code for the *App.vue*

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from "vue";

onMounted(() => {
  const routeHashContent = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  const hashParameters = new URLSearchParams(routeHashContent);

  const hashParameter = hashParameters.get("foo");

  if (hashParameter === null) {
    console.log("not found.");

    return;
  }

  console.log(hashParameter);
});
</script>

<template />
```

I could call the app with the url

> http://localhost:5173/#?foo=bar

to make it work. Is there a way to get rid of the hash? The url might look like so

> http://localhost:5173?foo=bar

Which code should I use instead of `const routeHashContent = window.location.hash.substring(1);` to get the queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an URL object by using

```
const url = new URL(window.location)
```

This object contains the url search parameters as the variable `searchParams`.

Access the params like this.

```
const bar = url.searchParams.get('foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is a good way to do this-

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const param1 = urlParams.get("token")

// Output will be null if there is no query param of named "token"
console.log(param1);
```

But if you are not using a full URL or using a custom URL to parse params from then you need to create a URL object first of that custom URL and apply search on it. [Why? read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#no_url_parsing).

```js
// Non window URL, then need to create URL object
const queryURL = new URL("https://example.com/over/there?name=ferret&age=11");

// Then apply search on newly created object
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryURL.search);

// Now, console the params,
console.log(urlParams.get("name"), urlParams.get("age"));
```